# A strange case in datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table WorkTBL

```
id  MyDate      Tdate
84  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:35:09.000
85  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:35:09.000
86  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:35:09.000
88  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:36:06.000
89  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:36:06.000
90  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:36:06.000
91  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:36:06.000
92  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:40:00.000
93  27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:40:00.000
95  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:03:22.000
96  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:03:22.000
98  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:04:35.000
102 04/05/2018  2018-05-04 22:57:42.000
103 04/05/2018  2018-05-04 22:57:42.000
104 04/05/2018  2018-05-04 22:57:42.000
```

I try to look for records between 01/03/2018 and 03/05/2018

I try this:

```
select id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tdate,103), Tdate
from WorkTBL
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tdate,103) >= '01/03/2018' and  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tdate,103)  <= '03/05/2018')
```

and this:

```
select id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tdate,103), Tdate
from WorkTBL
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),Tdate,103) between '01/03/2018' and  '03/05/2018')  order by id desc
```

But I get only these records:

```
95  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:03:22.000
96  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:03:22.000
98  02/05/2018  2018-05-02 16:04:35.000
```

Where is the rest? Why I do not get `88 27/04/2018  2018-04-27 13:36:06.000` for example?

Thanks

Comment: Guessing because you're not converting your literals? What is the local date format?

Comment: You compare *strings* instead of dates, at least format those strings using `yyyymmdd`

Comment: nothing strange about this, you are explicitly converting the dates to strings....and so, it is filtering them as strings (alphabetically). This means that `27/…..` is greater than `03/….`

Comment: local date format on my computer is:  dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @Gold doesn't matter, you are converting them to strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use always ANSI SQL Standard date format *YYYYMMDD*

```
select id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tdate,103) Tdate 
from WorkTBL
where cast(Tdate as date) >= '20180103' and  
      cast(Tdate as date) <= '20180503'
order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't convert date/times to strings for comparison!

Go for:

```
select id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Tdate,1 03), Tdate
from WorkTBL
where Tdate >= '2018-01-03' and 
      Tdate < '2018-05-04'
```

First, your comparisons are *strings*.  Strings are compared alphabetically, which explains your results.

Second, don't use `between` with dates and times.  Aaron Bertrand  has a very good [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on this subject.

Third, I removed the conversion to a date.  In general, the use of functions or conversions on a column prevents the use of indexes.  One of the very few exceptions is converting a datetime to a date.  However, the code is still simpler and cleaner without the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Right answer already accepted, but, to understand your problematic clearly, please use this:

```
select 
     [id]       =   [id]
    ,[MyDate]   =   convert(datetime, [MyDate], 103)
    ,[Tdate]    =   convert(datetime, [Tdate], 121)
from
    [#WorkTBL]
where
        convert(datetime, [Tdate], 121) >  convert(datetime, '01/03/2018', 103)
    and convert(datetime, [Tdate], 121) <  convert(datetime, '03/05/2018', 103);
```

Full testing query: https://pastebin.com/Csk1nHsC